# Element is not stretching to fit the widow even tho it is set to 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have created this http://jsfiddle.net/J5KMy/ it is a progress bar, it is looking good, however I can't seem to be able to stretch it! to make its width 100%, so it automatically stretch the steps to as wide the screen is.

[image]

Any idea what I am doing to actually make it not stretch? even tho the container is set to 100% width...

```
/*Progress Bar //////*/
 ol.progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
ol.progress-bar li {
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 0 20px 16px 20px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2em;
}
ol.progress-bar li.done {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #18BC9A;
}
ol.progress-bar li:before {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -2.2em;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
}
ol.progress-bar li.done:before {
    font-family:"icons";
    content:"\e613";
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #18BC9A;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

Comment: You can try a workaround with setting margin-right: 100px; in ol.progress-bar li.done:before

Comment: Did you try to add a `min-width` to your `li` elements? Like `li{min-width:150px;}` http://jsfiddle.net/J5KMy/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a block element it wasn't necessary to use `width:100%` - ol normally take 100% width, all `li`'s was without width so it's normal that they haven't take all the width it depend's of content. I modified your [jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5KMy/5/), add `display:table` to `ol` and `display:table-cell` on children so they take all width. And i add `box-sizing:border-box` because of default browser `padding-left` on ol,ul, otherwise your `ol` width gonna be `100% + browser padding-left`. Hope is what you want.

Comment: Thank you!! Can't believe I haven't thought about the table style! Worked brilliantly cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `box-sizing` to account for padding in the height/width, you can set each `li` element to 25%.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/d5dFB/6/)** | **[Full Screen View](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/d5dFB/6/embedded/result/)**

It gets pretty trippy when you can't display each `li` item on one line, but I'm assuming you can make way for that.

**CSS I Changed:**

```
 ol.progress-bar {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
ol.progress-bar li {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 0 20px 16px 20px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2em;
    width: 25%;
}
```

You can see more about `Box-Sizing` at [Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> **`border-box`**
>
> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J5KMy/10/)

I have used `display: table` for  `ol.progress-bar` and `dsplay: table-cell` for `ol.progress-bar li`

CSS

```
/*Progress Bar //////*/
 ol.progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;

    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ol.progress-bar li {
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: relative;
}
ol.progress-bar li.done {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #18BC9A;
}
ol.progress-bar li:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2.2em;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -17px;
    line-height: 1em;

}
ol.progress-bar li.done:before {
    font-family:"icons";
    content:"\e613";
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #18BC9A;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply some width to the li element

19% on the fiddle worked for me:

```
ol.progress-bar li {
    width: 19%;
    ...
}
```